# JavaFX - How to delete a specific Node from an AnchorPane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm using SceneBuilder 8.0.0 and JavaFX 8. 
I have a `Button btn` and a `Label lbl` attached to an `AnchorPane ap`. 
When the application starts, `btn` and `lbl` are attached to `ap`.

> **How can i delete one of these nodes ?** (i only know clear() method which deletes all the nodes from `ap`).
>   thanks.

Comment: You're trying to delete a node at runtime programmatically? Hiding or making the node invisible is probably a better idea than changing the layout on the fly by deleting things...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In JavaFX, nodes can simply be removed from a [Parent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html) (e.g. an [AnchorPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html)) using `.getChildren()` following by `.remove(Object o)`

### Reference

So if you have a direct reference to these Nodes, you could use the following code to remove the `Button` from the `AnchorPane`:

```
ap.getChildren().remove(btn);
```

### Lookup

If you, for some reason, don't have a reference to the `Button btn` you can use [lookup(String selector)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup-java.lang.String-) to find and remove it like so:

```
ap.getChildren().remove(ap.lookup('.button'));
```

### FXML

Or finally, since you are using SceneBuilder (and thus fxml) you could also **make sure you hava a Controller connected** and assign an id to your Button to get ahold of a reference and remove it like so:

```
// ... somewhere in your class
@FXML
private Button myButtonId;

// ... somewhere in a method
ap.getChildren().remove(myButtonId);
```

Comment: But I am getting NullPointerException whenever I am calling this method of controller class from my main class @Mike Rombout