# How to dynamically remove nodes in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, othello

```
@FXML AnchorPane gamePane;

public void gameStart() {
    if(!Started) {
        board = new Board();
        stones = new Circle[8][8];
        newTurn();
        applyBoard();
        Started = true;
    }
    else {
        DestroyBoard(); // <--- Erase all the stones 
        board = new Board();
        stones = new Circle[8][8];
        newTurn();
        applyBoard();
    }
}

public void applyBoard() { 
    for(int i = 0; i < board.boardsize; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < board.boardsize; j++) {
            if(board.board[i][j] != board.EMPTY) {
                if(board.board[i][j] == board.BLACK) {
                    stones[i][j] = new Circle(155 + 90 * j, 85 + 90 * i, 40);
                    stones[i][j].setFill(Color.BLACK);
                    gamePane.getChildren().add(stones[i][j]);
                }
                else if(board.board[i][j] == board.WHITE) {
                    stones[i][j] = new Circle(155 + 90 * j, 85 + 90 * i, 40);
                    stones[i][j].setFill(Color.WHITE);
                    gamePane.getChildren().add(stones[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public void DestroyBoard() { // <---Test Function and not worked!!
    gamePane.getChildren().remove(stones[3][3]);
}
```

I Tried to make if press start button again then all stones on board erased and  start a new game. As a first step I tried to erase one basic stone, but I can't delete any of stone on the board. What should I do to solve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX - How to delete a specific Node from an AnchorPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018663/javafx-how-to-delete-a-specific-node-from-an-anchorpane)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does work, but since you create a new `Board` and add the circles based on the initial data in this new instance, you get a board with twice as many circles minus the one you removed. I guess the code is deterministic so the positions and look of the circles remains the same as in the previous displayed version the result looks exactly the same as before...

Comment: if I do gamepane.getChildren().clear  at applyboard() function it works but anywhere except that, not working

Answer (score 3):

The stones are stored in an `ObservableList` within the `gamePane` container, which you access with the `getChildren()` method. The list has a very helpful `clear()` method that removes all items in the list.

So if you are just looking to remove all the stones from `gamePane`, just call this method:

```
gamePane.getChildren().clear();
```

Comment: thank for commenting.  if i call getChildren.clear() at appyboard() function, it worked but if i call that at destryboard() function, stones are still alive! what mistake did i do?

Comment: Do you call applyBoard() again right after DestroyBoard()?

Comment: Well, if you're deleting all the stones but adding them all back again right away, you won't notice them being removed.

Comment: that'r right so as a test case I tried to only remove a (3,3) located stone and also thats failed. I only can delete stones at applyboard() function which add stones at gamepane.getChildren() . without that function, no way to access stones